# what yeast should I use to bottle condition my blackberry sour?

Tags: bottle-conditioning, sour, wild-yeast

I brewed 2 batches of a blackberry sour in October 2010 that's nearly ready to bottle. 1 is with Roeselare, the 2nd is with lacto/pedio and both batches will be blended together after the new year. I'm trying to plan ahead so I can make sure that this goes without a hitch.

I don't want to have months of waiting ruined because I bottle-conditioned the wrong way. Which yeast should I use with corn sugs to bottle-condition this blackberry sour, and how long should I let the beer settle/carbonate before drinking?

Many thanks for any suggestions you can offer!
BG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some and add sugar (half starter, half priming), Let it sit with a balloon or something on it to tell if positive pressure is created. This will tell you if you still have some viable yeast to condition with or if you need to pitch new yeast.

If you do have to re-pitch I would probably pitch something VERY neutral and probably wouldn't do a starter, but somebody else may have input on that one. I would also shake/stir carefully but thoroughly to make sure you get even distribution.